# How to select multiple rows for one id or user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have two tables:
this is table info:

```
----------------
|s_id | s_name |
----------------
| 1 | Hevin    |
| 2 | Liza     |
---------------
```

This is table marks:

```
 -----------------------------------------
|id | s_id |makr1| mark2  |mark3 |
---------------------------------|------|
| 1 |  1   |  5  |   11   |  22   |
| 2 |  1   |  4  |   21   |  13   |
| 3 |  1   |  9  |   10   |  22   | 
| 4 |  2   |  2  |   9    |  10   |
| 5 |  2   |  6  |   17   |   8   |
| 6 |  2   | 15  |   20   |  12   |
----------------------------------------
```

I want to select two tables for every user was given below: 
for user 1:

ID: 1

Name:Hevin

```
-----------------------
|makr1| mark2  |mark3 |
-----------------------
|  5 |   11   |  22   |
|  4 |   21   |  13   |
|  9 |   10   |  22   | 
-----------------------
```

Table appear for user 2:

ID: 2

Name:Liza

```
-----------------------
|makr1| mark2  |mark3 |
----------------------- 
|  2 |   9    |  10   |
|  6 |   17   |   8   |
| 15 |   20   |  12   |
-----------------------
```

What is the MySQL query for do this work?

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Have you read any documentation about querying ? You should start from here [Query information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/retrieving-data.html)

You can do each table with this:

```
SELECT mark1,mark2,mark3 FROM marks where s_id = 1
```

Comment: Yes I red, I used this code but don't work for me:

SELECT info.*,marks.* FROM info
 INNER JOIN marks
 ON(info.s_id=marks.s_id)
 GROUP BY info.s_name";

Comment: When you do the group by all the rows with same info.s_name will become one and so you would need to AGGREGATE all the other columns you want.